# How to search for a value nested somewhere in a python object in VS Code while debugging

Tags: python, vscode-debugger

Is there some way in VS Code to search for a specific value inside an object that has many nested objects while debugging python code?  For example, when the code stops on a breakpoint, I can use the "Watch" panel to see an object's value, but that object has a lot of properties and sub-objects/sub-properties.  I'm pretty sure that the value "myuser" is in there somewhere, but I don't know how to find it aside from just wandering (expanding and collapsing) through the many properties.

Is there some way to search for that value while dubgging?